# Compiler Design First and follow

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, bottom-up, top-down

I have i doubt in a problem,trying to calculate FOLLOW(S) which needs FOLLOW(A) in it,but as A production is after S production,we have not calculated FOLLOW(A) yet.So,should we add FOLLOW(A) too inf FOLLOW(S)???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To compute FOLLOW(S) for any non-terminal S, apply the followwing rules until nothing can be added to any FOLLOW set.

1. Place $ in FOLLOW(S), where S is the start symbol.
2. If there is a production S -> CBD, then everything in FIRST(D) except epsilon is in FOLLOW(B).
3. If there is a proudction S -> CB, or a production S -> CBD, where FIRST(D) contains epsilon, then everything in FOLLOW(S) is in FOLLOW(B).

> Trying to calculate FOLLOW(S) which needs FOLLOW(A) in it,but as A
>   production is after S production,we have not calculated FOLLOW(A)
>   yet.So,should we add FOLLOW(A) too inf FOLLOW(S)???

SO, as you can see from the given grammar,

1. as per rule 1, the follow(S) will contains $.
2. Also, as per rule 2, S appears in bodies only followed by D(**non-terminal**), thus, everything except epsilon that is in FIRST(D) must be in FOLLOW(S). So, FOLLOW(S) must contain a.
3. Also,as per rule 3, considering the production A->ASD |epsilon and FIRST(D) contains epsilon, we should get FOLLOW(S) = FOLLOW(A).

***So, yes you need to calculate FOLLOW(A) before FOLLOW(S).***

And, FOLLOW(A) = everything in FIRST(S) except epsilon + b = {a,b}.

5. Also, in C-production, S is followed by b, so FOLLOW(S) must contain f.

**Hence, FOLLOW(S) = {a,b,f,$}.**

I don't know how you come to calculate that FOLLOW(A) is required for calculating FOLLOW(S). It is not the case. Please again go through the rules 1 to 3 mentioned in the starting of this answer.

Comment: Sorry for the presentation of my question.Considering the production       A->ASD |epsilon and D->epsilon,Using Rule 3 we should get FOLLOW(S)=FOLLOW(A).This is how i was needing FOLLOW(A).Why we didn't apply the 3rd rule here

Comment: @OMKAR-Yes, you need that. I missed that. You need to update that in your answer. I'll make the necessary edit. And, the answer mentioned in the book is wrong...

Comment: OK.Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: even after,referring another book they do not have b in FOLLOW(S),that's the reason i was hesitating to mark it as answer.

Comment: @OMKAR - Frankly speaking, even I am not sure of this answer. This type of question always puzzles me. You just leave it as it is, I'll tell you the final answer in a few days...

Comment: Its absolutely fine Sir,would be waiting for your response further.